# Types of Dana (दान) a person should give during his lifetime

Tags: daana

What are the types of Dana one should give during his lifetime, to whom and at what circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danas are of four types:

1. Without expecting returns - Nithya Dana.
2. To get rid of evils -  Naimithika Dana.
3. To attain success, wealth and a son - Kamya Daana.
4. To satisfy God - Vimala dana.

The recipients must be orthodox Brahmins for merit to be attained, because only they are ordained to receive donations (because they recite Vedas daily which has power to repel sins that are inevitably attached to any donation)

Source--Garuda Purana  Chapter III.

Answer (score 0):

As per Gita, there are 3 types of gift/charity depending on 3 modes of *prakruti*:

#### Charity as part of duty

> BG 17.20 - That charity is referred to as born of ***sattva*** which gift is given with the idea that it ought to be given, to one who will not serve in return, and at the (proper) place, (proper) time and to a (proper) person.

#### Charity with desires of return

> BG 17.21 - But the charity which is given expecting reciprocation, or again, with a desire for its result, and which is given grudgingly,- that is considered to be born of ***rajas***.

#### Charity wrongly done due to ignorance

> BG 17.22 - The charity which is made at an improper place and time, and to undeserving persons, without proper treatment and with disdain, is declared to be born of ***tamas***